# How to change audio on this HTML, JS, CSS audio player

Tags: javascript, html, css

I got this source code from YouTube, I want to change the audio but I can't do that(seem to be encrypted) cuz every time when I change the audio the old audio play only. please help I'M newbie to js dev.

this is the source code: https://github.com/kaizhelam/Music-Player
Thanks

I got this source code from YouTube, I want to change the audio but I can't do that(seem to be encrypted) cuz everytime when I change the audio the old audio play only. please help I'M newbie to JS dev.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that in `script.js` the music is defined in an array `music_list`, that uses JS objects to keep track of the audio file, name, author, and image of the that particular song.

This is what the array looks like.

```
const music_list = [
    {
        img : 'images/stay.png',
        name : 'Stay',
        artist : 'The Kid LAROI, Justin Bieber',
        music : 'music/stay.mp3'
    },
    {
        img : 'images/fallingdown.jpg',
        name : 'Falling Down',
        artist : 'Wid Cards',
        music : 'music/fallingdown.mp3'
    },
    {
        img : 'images/faded.png',
        name : 'Faded',
        artist : 'Alan Walker',
        music : 'music/Faded.mp3'
    },
    {
        img : 'images/ratherbe.jpg',
        name : 'Rather Be',
        artist : 'Clean Bandit',
        music : 'music/Rather Be.mp3'
    }
];
```

If you wanted to simply add a song to the list, you take an audio file that is either MP3, WAV, or OGG, as these are the audio formats JS supports. You put the audio file in the music folder, and then take an image for it and put it in the images folder.

Then, you want to add this element to the `music_list` array in `script.js`, and replace the capitalized text with the name of the file, the name of the song, the artist, and music file name. Remember to include the file extensions!

```
{
   img : 'images/YOUR_IMAGE',
   name : 'YOUR_NAME',
   artist : 'YOUR_ARTIST',
   music : 'music/YOUR_MUSIC_FILE'
}
```

If you wanted to replace one of the songs, you can add the files as before, then delete the ones you don't want anymore, and replace the links in the element that you want to replace. Hope this helps!

Comment: I already did that but nothing was change

Comment: Remember to save the file and refresh the page.

Comment: I did but nothing change

Comment: try to clear cache

Comment: Can you show what your code looks like?